# Marquee in android

Tags: android, layout

In my android application i need to scroll a marquee text continuously.
in my Xml i have this code:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/widget28"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"                
   android:singleLine="true"        
   android:ellipsize="marquee"
   android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
   android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
   android:scrollHorizontally="true"
   android:textColor="#ff4500"
   android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout " />
```

And in my Java source code i have:

```
TextView tv = (TextView )findViewById(R.id.widget28);
tv.setSelected(true);
```

Now my issue is this code works fine and marquee runs fine even if the focus is not on the control but the scrolling of text is not complete.I need the text to scroll completely.If i add space to the text both before and after the text it works fine but that is not good programming. Is there a good way to this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to scroll continuously, you must use this in your xml:

```
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
```

It is not necessary to put setSelected(true); in the file

PS. You must only click on it when the focus changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your issue.

I have copied your code and inserted the `TextView` in a `RelativeLayout` with `fill_parent` for the 2 axes and it works fine (isn't that what you want?) :

[image]

I have tested that code on default emulator 2.1 and 2.2. No trouble.

Here is my class :

```
public class TextViewMarquee extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.textview);
        findViewById(R.id.widget28).setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

And the associated xml :

```
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget28"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout"
        android:textColor="#ff4500" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And that's actually all, no mystery line in the manifest or style or ...

Comment: Hello Sephy
How are you using  RelativeLayout with fill_parent for the 2 axes.
I am using the textview inside table layout and what i am getting is like it starts scrolling and stops once it reaches end of text like ,i will be able to see these text on screen application that shows how to use RelativeLayout  and later again it starts from simple application.In short only Simple app is what gets disappeared and not the full text as shown by u.

Comment: Thanks Sephy.I just want to have a look as where am i going wrong.Please post it.

Comment: That darn marquee feature never would work for me either. I think there's a marquee conspiracy

Comment: Well, actually, I have no idea... I'll detail my config and code in my post so that you can compare with yours...

Comment: Thanks Sephy.Yes  its working fine in 2.1,2.2 but not in 1.5.I need it to work in 1.5.

Comment: You should mention the system you are working with when you ask a question, that helps. Then I don't know why it's not working in 1.5 sorry

Comment: I have tested quite a lot and coulnt find any way to make the text of the marquee run in a circular way in Android 1.5, this is strange.

Comment: Sorry Sephy.Will remember to mention the system hereafter.
Hmmm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this::

```
<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"                
   android:singleLine="true"        
   android:ellipsize="marquee"
   android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
   android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
   android:scrollHorizontally="true"
   android:textColor="#ff4500"
   android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout " 
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:freezesText="true"></TextView>
```

Comment: Thanks Jorgesys.
if we set focusable true,it works only if the control has focus.Instead remove focus and set selected as true then it works fine.
It doesnot work in android 1.5 emulator.I am trying for that.

Comment: Hi Reshmi, yes definitely it needs to have the focus to work, and it works on Android 1.5 Emulator too, install the latest SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Guys, TextView scrolls its text ONLY when it's focused. As soon as it loses the focus, text scrolling will stop.

Comment: This is why we added .setSelected(true);